# win32 save if file already exists

Tags: file, winapi, save

I'm writing a notepad program, and implemented a saveas feature ( with save dialog box, etc ). I tried searching for a way to only save ( not show save dialog box if the file already exists ) but couldn't find anything. How would I do that? The code I have for the saveas feature is:

```
case ID_FILE_SAVEAS:
            {
                OPENFILENAME ofn;
                char szFileName[ MAX_PATH ] = "";
                ZeroMemory( &ofn, sizeof( ofn ) );

                ofn.lStructSize = sizeof( ofn );
                ofn.hwndOwner   = hwnd;
                ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
                ofn.lpstrFile   = szFileName;
                ofn.nMaxFile    = MAX_PATH;
                ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
                ofn.Flags       = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

                if( GetSaveFileName( &ofn ) )
                {
                    // DO FUN STUFF
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just DO FUN STUFF. Or explain your issue more clearly.

Comment: You need to keep track of the filename.  Use a variable, assign it when you open the file.  If the user hits Ctrl+S then check if the variable is assigned.  If it is then no problem, just save the file.  If it is not then you need the SaveAs dialog.

Comment: Anytime I click on save or saveas, the save dialog box appears, even if the file already exists. basically, I want to be able to open a file, make changes, then save without having the save dialog box show so i cant change the name of the file

Comment: @HansPassant I got the first part down, I'm actualy using a listbox that links the file with the same of the file. But I'm unsure as how to just save the file.

Comment: Whatever you do inside `if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn)) { ... }` - just do that.

Comment: So I don't need to call GetSaveFileName( &ofn ) function if I just want to save?

Comment: You call `GetSaveFileName` to retrieve a filename for saving from the user. If you already have a filename you obviously don't have to ask the user for one. @Paul basically answered your question. Also acknowledge that ASCII is pretty much last century. Consider compiling for UNICODE. People are crazy and put all kinds of fünkÿ characters in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prerequisite: You need to keep track of the filename that you have loaded...

case ID_FILE_SAVE:
    {
    if (... there is already a filename loaded ...)
        {
        // open the filename that is being tracked...
        // write data to the file as needed...
        // close the file...

        break;
        }

    // there is no file loaded yet so fall through to the next case...
    }

case ID_FILE_SAVEAS:
    {
    OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
    char szFileName[ MAX_PATH ] = "";

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof( ofn );
    ofn.hwndOwner   = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
    ofn.lpstrFile   = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile    = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
    ofn.Flags       = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

    if( GetSaveFileName( &ofn ) )
        {
        // open the selected filename...
        // write data to the file as needed...
        // close the file...

        // track the selected filename for later use in ID_FILE_SAVE...
        }

    break;
    }
```